# Storing output of Stored Procedure in file after calling it from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures, output

I am trying to call a SP (Ola's maintenance script!) on a remote server (that part of the code works), and the output of the SP is the results of DBCC CHECKDB (so it's in the Message tab).

I tried to put together some code to capture this Message output into a file on the remote server, but the file is not being created, though the SP completes fine.

```
$OutputFile = "\\XXX\E$\SQLAdmin\DatabaseCheckDB\ScriptOutput\ScriptOutput.txt"

$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $event) Out-File -filepath $OutputFile -inputobject $event.Message };

 $SqlConnection.add_InfoMessage($handler); 
 $SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true;
 $SqlConnection = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=XXX;DataBase=master;Integrated Security=SSPI")
 $SqlConnection.Open() | Out-Null

$cmd = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck", $SqlConnection)
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'

$cmd.Parameters.Add("@Databases","ALL_DATABASES") | Out-Null

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null

$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here? THanks in advance!

Comment: Does `.ExecuteNonQuery()` still allow info messages to come back?

Comment: @Aaron, from what I read piping @cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() to NULL suppresses the info from that function, but the output of that function only tells how may rows were returned from the calling SP. In this case it would return -1 since no rows are returned from Ola's script on a successful call. But I'm hoping to get the Message output into a text file so I can have that as proof the checkdb was clean.

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() (regardless of where in your pipe you put it) also has the effect of suppressing resultsets from coming back *at all* - so my question is, when you use ExecuteNonQuery(), is it possible that it also suppresses messages? I don't know, hence the question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand answer below, so it doesn't suppress messages and I needed to put the handler in the right spot after creating a sqlconnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the SQL Powershell module installed (sqlps)?  If so, then you can use this and pipe the output from the Verbose stream (which contains printed messages from SQL), to your file.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'DBCC CHECKDB' `
    -ServerInstance '(local)' `
    -Database 'tempdb' `
    -Verbose 4>&1 |
        Out-File c:\temp\test.txt
```

If that isn't an option, then I think I have spotted the problem in your original code - you wire up the InfoMessage event, but you then proceed to create a brand new SqlConnection.  This new SqlConnection doesn't have the event handler on it, and so won't respond to any of the printed messages.

Try replacing

```
$SqlConnection.add_InfoMessage($handler); 
$SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true;
$SqlConnection = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=XXX;DataBase=master;Integrated Security=SSPI")
```

with

```
$SqlConnection = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=XXX;DataBase=master;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$SqlConnection.add_InfoMessage($handler); 
$SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true;
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, that was it, the order of creating a new connection and then wiring up the InfoMessage event. I had to also throw in -append when defining the out-file so it didn't keep overwriting the contents of the file.